# R: Mutate a list of lists of different lengths into a vector of lists (as part of a Data Frame)

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, bioinformatics, lapply

I have a csv file that translates into a data.frame like this (- are other irrelevant columns)

```
C1    C2     C3    C4    C5    Start     End        C8
A     1      -      -     -    [1,4,7]   [3,6,10]    -
A     2      -      -     -     [12]     [14]        -
A     3      -      -     -     [16,19]  [17,21]     -
A     4      -      -     -     [22]     [24]        -
```

Where I intend to compute much later on the ranges between each member of Start and End iteratively.

Of course that notation is useful to evaluate literally in Python and not really in R, but I gave it a try using this function:

`````
Format the Start and End columns into lists
```{r}
vect <- function(fac){
    str <- as.character(fac)
    return(as.list(strsplit(substr(str,2,nchar(str)-1),",")))
    #return(data.frame(lapply(str, `length<-`, max(lengths(str)))))
}
````
`````

and

````
Read in experimental data
```{r}
data <- read.csv("elution_peptides_positions_arath.csv", sep=",",header=TRUE)
data <- mutate(data,Start=vect(Start),End=vect(End))
data$X <- NULL
```
````

The problem is that that gives away a list as a column (instead of a vector), I don't know why!

```
 > class(data$Start)
[1] "list"
```

When I try to convert the list into a vector with

```
data <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, unlist))
```

it gives away this error:

```
Error: wrong result size (35676), expected 35568 or 1
```

I need them to be a vector to apply a function to sort them by the first element (I guess the following would work):

```
id <- order(sapply(data$Start,function(i)i[1])) 
data <- data[order(data$Start),]
```

but doing so over the list gives away this error:

```
 Error in order(data_protein$Start) : 
 unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
```

So I supposed that I should convert that column into a vector.

What is causing the first error? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Your `vect()` function is well-written except for two issues. First, you don't need the `as.list()` coercion because [`strsplit()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) always returns a list. Second, you should coerce the numbers from character to numeric, especially if you're planning on numerically ordering by them later. Stringified numbers lexicographically order incorrectly. (Also, in this case, you can omit the [`return()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html) call since the value of the final expression evaluated within a function is returned automatically, even without a `return()`, although either way works.)

So we have:

```
vect <- function(fac) {
    str <- as.character(fac);
    lapply(strsplit(substr(str,2L,nchar(str)-1L),','),as.integer);
}; ## end vect()

df$Start <- vect(df$Start);
df$End <- vect(df$End);
df;
##   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5   Start      End C8
## 1  A  1  -  -  - 1, 4, 7 3, 6, 10  -
## 2  A  2  -  -  -      12       14  -
## 3  A  3  -  -  -  16, 19   17, 21  -
## 4  A  4  -  -  -      22       24  -
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(C1=c('A','A','A','A'),C2=c(1L,2L,3L,4L),C3=c('-','-','-','-'),C4=c('-','-',
'-','-'),C5=c('-','-','-','-'),Start=c('[1,4,7]','[12]','[16,19]','[22]'),End=c('[3,6,10]',
'[14]','[17,21]','[24]'),C8=c('-','-','-','-'),stringsAsFactors=F);
```

---

There is an inherent problem with your intent to convert the list column to a vector. The R data.frame type enforces that all columns have the same length. Hence, if you try to unlist the `Start` and `End` columns into an atomic vector, their length will exceed the length of all other columns, hence the error message.

If you want to order the data.frame by the first number in each `Start` vector, your `id` calculation is perfect, although it can be made more concise as follows:

```
df[order(sapply(df$Start,`[`,1L)),];
##   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5   Start      End C8
## 1  A  1  -  -  - 1, 4, 7 3, 6, 10  -
## 2  A  2  -  -  -      12       14  -
## 3  A  3  -  -  -  16, 19   17, 21  -
## 4  A  4  -  -  -      22       24  -
```

(It should be noted that this example data.frame already possessed the order in question prior to running the above line of code. This is why it is always good to consider the problem of [test coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_coverage) when creating test data.)